# Can't find any references using 'semantic-symref-symbol'

Tags: emacs, cedet, emacs-semantic

I'm getting `No references found` message whenever I use "semantic-symref-symbol" (C-c , g) trying to get all the references to any symbol, whether the symbol is a C++ class member variable or a local variable, it just couldn't find any reference. The gtag database are under my project root. In my .emacs file I have the following:

```
(require 'semanticdb-global)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c-mode)
(semanticdb-enable-gnu-global-databases 'c++-mode)
```

When I type "global -xs symbol" under command line, it shows all the reference to the symbol correctly. But why semantic couldn't find anything? On the other hand, 'semantic-symref' works fine on looking for references of a class or class member function, but it doesn't work for variables.

Is it simply a bug, or am I missing anything that keeps symbol reference from working?

Answer (score 1):

This problem is with how GNU Global is used in Semantic came up on the mailing list the other day.  GNU Global lets you find occurances of tags (with -r) or random symbols (-s), and Semantic uses the -r flag, and the variables you mention are not considered tags by 
GNU Global.

In the cedet-global.el support file the function `cedet-gnu-global-search`, it was proposed to use or add the -s flag when searching for a 'symbol.  I don't know what the resolution will be at this time, however.

You can see the whole thread on the cedet-devel mailing list:

http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?forum_name=cedet-devel&max_rows=25&style=ultimate&viewmonth=201103